# \(Double) rounding

Tags: swift

Aside from overriding the current method that does the conversion to string, is there a nice way to round the double/string representation of it to 3 decimal places?

Comment: Do you want to round, or do you just want to chop off the digits after the 3rd?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an extension, and then specify the precision as you call it.

```
extension Double {
    func format(f: String) -> String {
        return NSString(format: "%\(f)f", self)
    }
}

let myDouble = 1.234567
println(myDouble.format(".3")
```

Comment: This isn't rounding.  This is simply displaying 3 decimal places without any rounding involved.  Your answer will print `1.234` but were it rounded, it should print `1.235`.

Comment: thanks. amazing they didn't include things like this. not to mention no subscripting strings...

Comment: @nhgrif actually it does round, try it out in your playground.  It maintains the C printf behavior which is to round to the requested digits.